# Quartz.Net scheduler service does not start automatically on startup

Tags: c#, sql-server, sockets, windows-services, quartz.net

I have developed a *Quartz.Net* windows service to run scheduled jobs and I have set up an *SQLite* jobstore for it to work. Here are the settings of my `AdoJobStore`:

```
# SQLite settings
quartz.jobStore.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
quartz.jobStore.dataSource = default
quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = qrtz_
quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SQLiteDelegate, Quartz
quartz.dataSource.default.provider = SQLite-10
quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString = Data Source=.\jobs.db;Version=3
```

Before giving you a headache, I should say that this is a working solution! That means the job store works just fine! Each job consists of running an `.exe` file that will get its parameters from an `SQL Server` database using a connection string that is stored in a text file.

So if the service is started automatically, everything works fine.

After installing the Windows service, we give it a username that has access to the destination database in service's *Log On* tab. We set the service to start automatically (and have tried the *Automatic Delayed* mode as well). In the *Recovery* tab of the service we also command it to *Restart* in case it crashes.

However, the service does not seems to be starting by itself on some machines and that has kept me wondering for quite a while now. On machines with failure, this is what my service logs when it fails to start:

```
2015-02-13 15:09:15,674 [1] ERROR Quartz.Server.QuartzServer [(null)] - Server initialization failed:Unable to bind scheduler to remoting.
Quartz.SchedulerException: Unable to bind scheduler to remoting. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.GetMachineIp()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel.SetupMachineName()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider sinkProvider, IAuthorizeRemotingConnection authorizeCallback)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IClientChannelSinkProvider clientSinkProvider, IServerChannelSinkProvider serverSinkProvider)
   at Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter.RegisterRemotingChannelIfNeeded()
   at Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter.Bind(IRemotableQuartzScheduler scheduler)
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Bind()
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Initialize()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Initialize()
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.Instantiate()
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.GetScheduler()
   at Quartz.Server.QuartzServer.Initialize() [See nested exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.GetMachineIp()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel.SetupMachineName()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider sinkProvider, IAuthorizeRemotingConnection authorizeCallback)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IClientChannelSinkProvider clientSinkProvider, IServerChannelSinkProvider serverSinkProvider)
   at Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter.RegisterRemotingChannelIfNeeded()
   at Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter.Bind(IRemotableQuartzScheduler scheduler)
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Bind()
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Initialize()]
```

The service is installed on host `127.0.0.1` port `555` and does not seem to need a dependency because it works under some other machines.

I have a feeling that the service is trying to start itself before there is an access to the database or before the `TCP` host is established. But if that's the case, why does it work on other devices?

I have asked the same question before but have failed to find a working answer. Any help from `Quartz.Net` dev team or *Windows Services* experts is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer. I'm not part of the Quartz.net dev team, nor am I an expert on Windows services

> The service is installed on host 127.0.0.1 port 555 and does not seem to need a dependency because it works under some other machines.

Your reasoning is false. It could be that the required services just **happen** to have always started on the other machines, but without setting a dependency this is not guaranteed.

So, since you are getting a DNS error, I would suggest you start by setting your service do that it depends on **Dnscache** and **Tcpip** .

Comment: makes sense. I should try this out. Will let you know if it worked.

Comment: I don't have the services with the names you mentioned above but I can see `TCP/IP NETBIOS Helper` and `DNS Client` in my installed services.

Comment: `Dnscache` is the Service name and  `DNS Client` is the display name for the same service.  `lmhosts` is the service name for `TCP/IP NETBIOS Helper` , but I'm not sure whether NetBios would be needed. `Tcpip` is actually a device rather than a service, but it can still be included as a dependency.

Comment: damn! i really had high hopes for this. but neither of them work. i have two colleagues who both have Win7 on exactly the same type of laptop. One working and the other not. It has become so hard to detect the problem. How am I supposed to know what my service really depends on? And why the "Automatic Delayed" startup type does not work either? Any suggests would still be appreciated.